# generate a random cluster of points around a given point python

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is if there is something built into any of the python libraries that would allow me to generate a random cluster of 3D points (x,y,z) around a given x,y,z point?

I can't seem to find anything similar to this but I am new to python so I'm not sure if its blindingly obvious or I have to try do it manually by using random numbers within a certain range of the given point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `random` library;

This will give you poitns uniformly spaced aroudn the original point.

```
import random
source = [x,y,z]

deviationFromPoint = 10

for _ in range(numberOfAdditionalPoints):
  newCoords = [source[i] + random.random() * deviationFromPoint for i in range(3)]
  newPoint = Point(newCoords) # Or whatever constructor you have for your points.
```

If you want a different distribution, jsut use a different distribution, look in the documentation of `random`

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question in a sense because I was asking did something exist to do this but you did solve my problem so thanks! I will accept when I can

Comment: Well, are you using a library to deal with the 3D points? or have you just created your own class?

Comment: I think this answer is close but the set of points would be confined in a cube not a sphere

Comment: @SawanVaidya that wasn't specified in the question, but if that's a requirement, then you could run a check that the point is farther away than the specified deviation, you throw it away and try again.